# Passing Database Name or the Whole Database as Variable

Tags: c#, database, linq, variables

I am refactoring my code by extracting functions.

Originally I have one huge main function which immediately gets the database using the dbName passed in from outside at the very first line and then does some other things based on the database.

Now I want to make those other things some small functions called by the now-smaller main function.

Those small functions need to access the same database.

Do I -

1. pass the dbName every time calling a small function and get the database inside it

   - this seems somewhat redundant, if I have n small functions then I need to get the database n times
2. pass the whole database into the small function and use it right away

   - would this cause performance issues?

---

And another question:

I know we can use

`var table = database.GetCollection<table>()`
to get and store the table into a variable so we can use it instead of getting it again every time we wanna find something.

But does it work when the action I wanna perform is **modifying**?

If I use `table` to **insert and then find**, can I get the record I just inserted?

I mean, does `table` mean the table before I inserted?

Comment: What are you using to access the database? Entity Framework?

Comment: I think your question doesn't fit well to this site. Here, on StackOverflow, we usually deal with **"not working"** code (at least **"working not like expected"**). If your code is actually works and you want a code-review - you may try [another site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is a good way to get started dividing your code into areas of functionality.  I think you are looking for a Data Access Layer. A separate class with static methods that take care of all communication with the database. The size of your data will dictate how much you can store locally in data sets and data tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options 2 is most likely the way to go given the information you have provided.

You will not be passing the entire database into the function, just a reference to it as most objects are passed by reference, not by value (unless they are a [`ValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

`table` should be a reference to the table (like `DbSet<tablename>`) , not the table in its current state (if you want that you need to call `table.ToList()` which should return `List<tablename>`and store that instead.)

So calling `table.Add(object)` and then `table.Find(object.ID)` should return the object as it current is in the database